# How to sort and display mongo entries grouped by date in the meteor helpers / templates

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

Hello and sorry for my broken English.

I drew a picture in Paint so you can better understand my question / intention:
[Sketch in Paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDdDy.png)

I want to build this html structure on my website like in the picture.

My mongodb structure:

```
{ "_id" : "doZfpnSFPzuPCi69W", "title" : "TodoA", "date" : "2016-10-03" }  
{ "_id" : "kLdCQotDBPmB3FGzY", "title" : "TodoB", "date" : "2016-10-03" }
{ "_id" : "fgAoaq53oNdKQSHXv", "title" : "TodoA", "date" : "2016-10-04" }
{ "_id" : "L6v4FC5PpyHjCkkpd", "title" : "TodoB", "date" : "2016-10-04" }
```

I know how to display all entries in my template with "each":

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  {{#each showTodos}}
  ...
 {{/each}}
</template>
```

However, I have no idea how to achieve my purpose that you can see on my picture. I know how to use if-else in meteor, but I have no idea how to achieve this html-structure with if-statement. Can you help me with code and logic, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to nest two `{{#each}}` loops, one for the dates, and for each date, all matching documents.

But first you need to find the unique dates! To do this use underscore's [_.uniq()](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) function.

html:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  {{#each uniqueDates}}
    this
    {{#each todos}}
      ...
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

js:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  uniqueDates(){
    const dates = myCollection.find({},{sort: {date: 1}})
      .map((doc)=>{return doc.date});
    return _.uniq(dates,true);
  },
  todos(){
    return myCollection.find({date: this});
  }
};
```

Applying [.map()](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-map) to the cursor allows you to extract only the dates as an array. Then you use `_.uniq()` on the array to get the unique values. The second argument to `.uniq()` tells it that the values are already sorted.